# Golang set struct field using reflect

Tags: go, reflection

I am currently doing the following

```
func Test(controller interface{}) {
    controllerType := reflect.TypeOf(controller)
    controllerFunc := reflect.ValueOf(controller)
    controllerStruct := reflect.New(controllerType.In(0))
    for i := 0; i < controllerStruct.Elem().NumField(); i++ {
        if controllerStruct.Elem().Field(i).Kind().String() == "ptr" {
            controllerStruct.Elem().Field(i).Set(
                reflect.New(
                    controllerStruct.Elem().Field(i).Type(),
                ).Elem(),
            )
        }
    }
    controllerFunc.Call([]reflect.Value{
        controllerStruct.Elem(),
    })
}
```

Using the following function call

```
Test(controllers.Test.IsWorking)

type Test struct {
    Name string
    H    *Hello
}

type Hello struct {
    Friend string
}

func (t Test) IsWorking() {
    log.Println(t.H)
}
```

`t.H` is always `nil` even tho I am setting it on the for loop. Also I am not sure if this is the correct way to make this since what about if `Hello` struct contains another pointer to a struct. Is there a better method to achieve what I am trying to do and why is `t.H` `nil` if I am setting it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t.H` is nil because you are giving an incorrect value in `Set` method. You are getting `Value` of `reflect.New`'s return (`reflect.New(...).Elem()` is `Hello` type, no `*Hello` type and type of `H` field is `*Hello` type). If you change the type of `H`field to `Hello` type, you will see that it is initialized okay Then, you should do this:

```
controllerStruct.Elem().Field(i).Set(
    reflect.New(
        controllerStruct.Elem().Field(i).Type().Elem(),
    ),
)
```

Value of `reflect.New(controllerStruct.Elem().Field(i).Type().Elem())` is a new `*Hello` struct.

I hope that it's useful to you! :-)